# Find shortest path in directed, weighted graph that visits every node with no restrictions on revisiting nodes and edges

Tags: python, networkx, graph-theory

I'm using the [NetworkX](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/algorithms/index.html) Python library. A more extensive description of the problem I'm trying to solve is [here](https://github.com/jonluca/AmazeSolver).

I'd like to find both 1) *a* valid path that visits every node at least once and 2) the *shortest* path, based on edge weights, that visits every node at least once.

This sounds like a variation of the Travelling Salesman Problem. The other thing of note is that the graph is *almost* undirected - most of the nodes are bidirectionally connected, it's only a certain few (<20% of all nodes) that are unidirectionally connected.

I looked over the NetworkX algorithms but none seemed to satisfy this question.

The code used to generate the graph is:

```py
    def generate_graph(self):
        ind = (12, 0)
        self.ball = ind
        locs = [ind]
        while len(locs):
            next_loc = locs.pop()
            if not self.nodes[next_loc]:
                self.nodes[next_loc] = AmazeGameLocation(next_loc)
                self.paths.add_node(self.nodes[next_loc])

            moves = [("U", (-1, 0)), ("D", (1, 0)), ("L", (0, -1)), ("R", (0, 1))]
            for move in moves:
                next_move_loc = add_tuples(move[1], next_loc)
                if self.is_move_possible(next_move_loc):
                    next_attempt = add_tuples(move[1], next_move_loc)
                    weight = 1
                    while self.is_move_possible(next_attempt):
                        next_move_loc = next_attempt
                        next_attempt = add_tuples(move[1], next_move_loc)
                        weight += 1
                    if not self.nodes[next_move_loc]:
                        self.nodes[next_move_loc] = AmazeGameLocation(next_move_loc)
                        self.paths.add_node(self.nodes[next_move_loc])
                        locs.append(next_move_loc)
                    self.paths.add_edge(self.nodes[next_loc], self.nodes[next_move_loc], weight=weight)
                    self.nodes[next_loc].dirs[move[0]] = self.nodes[next_move_loc]
```

A sample graph is [here](https://github.com/jonluca/AmazeSolver/blob/master/graph.png).

More information about this graph and issue is on my GitHub, [here](https://github.com/jonluca/AmazeSolver).

Answer (score 0):

> I'd like to find both 1) a valid path that visits every node at least once and 2) the shortest path, based on edge weights, that visits every node at least once.

For 1): that's pretty simple, you can try to find for instance a [spanning tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree) of your graph. You can then build a path that visits all vertices in your graph by traversing this spanning tree.

For 2): Let `G` be your graph, you can then build `G'` the 'metric completion' of `G`, meaning that the vertices of `G'` are the vertices of `G`, and for any couple of vertices `u, v`, there is an edge `u,v` in `G'`, weighted with the weight of the shortest path from `u` to `v` in `G`.
Then all you have to do is solve a TSP on `G'` to obtain the solution you look for on `G`.